# filter function does not filter

Tags: matlab

I have a notch filter designed for 50Hz. Then I generated the filter design code with Filter Design app:

```
function Hd = filter_notch
Fs=500; Fnotch=50; BW=1; Apass=1; 
[b, a] = iirnotch(Fnotch/(Fs/2), BW/(Fs/2), Apass);
Hd     = dfilt.df2(b, a);
```

This is its frequency response:

[image]

Now, I filter input signal with this filter:

```
filter_block=filter_notch;
out_signal=filter(filter_block,in_signal);
```

but to my surprise at notch frequency, it amplifies the signal for about +10dB!! Here is the zoomed version. Blue is output, Red is Input. What is going on here?!

[image]

Comment: I've never seen `filter` used with only two arguments...

Comment: @MBaz If you have a filter object, like here, it's used with 2 arguments.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/filter.html?s_tid=doc_ta

Comment: Got it -- I even searched for it on mathworks.com and didn't find. I've never used Matlab objects (I'm old school).

Comment: Have you tried convolving manually instead of using `filter()`, to check if the problem comes from your filter object or your call to the function?

Comment: @MBaz I'm old school too. That's why the panic :)

Comment: @FlorentEcochard No I haven't. But that filter object is very standard thing. It's MATLAB auto-generated code, it must work.

Comment: Right. What about trying to filter using `b` and `a`? I know I'm insisting on trying to incriminate the "filter" object but I think it is possible that this is an implementation problem (df2) relatively to your signal.

Comment: I just tried on Matlab to apply your filter to an impulse signal and freqz the result, and it works fine...

Comment: Is original signal presented as red curve? If so, how many samples you used to plot the PSD, plus you have to ignore initial samples to let the filter settle.

Comment: Try with an input that is not at -110 dB. You're probably seeing a lot of roundoff and floating-point approximation errors.